# How to get data from google sheet to my Gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I tried to get some data from google sheet and display it in Gmail addons.
When i tried to run getValue() function i am getting error like below.

> You do not have permission to call openById (line 29, file "Code")Dismiss

This is my code.gs file code

```
     function createWidgetCard() {
   return CardService
      .newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(
          CardService.newCardHeader()
              .setTitle('Widget demonstration')
              .setSubtitle('Check out these widgets')
              .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.SQUARE)
              .setImageUrl(
                  'https://www.example.com/images/headerImage.png'))
      .addSection(
           CardService.newCardSection()
               .setHeader('Simple widgets')  // optional
               .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(
                   'These widgets are display-only. ' +
                   'A text paragraph can have multiple lines and ' +
                   getValue()))
               .addWidget(CardService.newImage().setImageUrl(
                   'https://www.example.com/images/mapsImage.png')))
      .addCardAction(CardService.newCardAction().setText('Gmail').setOpenLink(
          CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl('https://mail.google.com/mail')))
      .build();
 }



//get data from sheet
function getValue(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("181tnith14lu8ttAvtqsU3gHi32-UjcrPqH5Pjuenk5A");
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var lastRaw = sheet.getLastRow();
   var text = sheet.getRange(lastRaw, 3.0).getValue();
   Logger.log("text");
   return text;
}
```

This is my manifest file code(appscript.json)

```
     {
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"    
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Finetech Addon",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "createWidgetCard"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```

My requirement is accessing sheet and get some data and display it on Gmail addon. It could be very helpful if anyone can provide correct code snipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the scope for using Spreadsheet is required to be added to "oauthScopes" of manifests. So please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` to "oauthScopes" in `appsscript.json`. And try again.

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.